# How to predict result of sigmoid function in Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, octave

I am taking Coursera Machine Learning course and I am kind of confused with the sigmoid function.

I implemented the sigmoid function like:

```
g = 1 ./ (1+e.^(-z));
```

and wrote a function to predict the result and it looks like

```
p = sigmoid(X*theta) >= 0.5
```

The questions says

```
"For a student with an Exam 1 score
of 45 and an Exam 2 score of 85, you should expect to see an admission
probability of 0.776"
```

But I am not sure how those two x values have to be plugged into the function that I made.

If the theta is 0.218, how does Exam scores of 45 and 85 give us the probability of 0.776? Can someone explain?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability is given by the sigmoid function,

```
 p = sigmoid(X*theta)
 # Since there are two inputs, the model will have 2 weights and a bias.
 p = sigmoid(0.45*w1+0.85*w2+b)
 # The actual output is given by
 y = 0.776
 # Loss function
 loss = (p-y)^2
 # Find the weights by minimizing the loss function using gradient descent.
```

Comment: Thanks but i am not quite sure. Sigmoid function is defined to have only one parameter, I am not sure where the w1 and w1 and b come from.

Comment: w1, w2 and b are what you defined as theta in your formula and X is [0.45, 0.85].  The input to the sigmoid is one number only.

Comment: so w1, w2, and b are the parameters derived from my gradient descent?

Comment: yes, i ran the above code to get : sigmoid(-0.1806*0.45+0.9136*0.85+0.5473)

Comment: Thanks! By the way, just an additional question. When we first test our cost function, i see that the assignment test it with vectors of zeros first and vectors of non-zero. What's the difference and which one is the correct way?

Comment: @user7677413 if this answer addresses your initial question adequately please accept it and move on. It's considered extremely bad form on SO to hold it "hostage" to force the answerer to provide a further "service", especially when such a second question should be a different, independently posted question in the first place. Not to mention this question isn't about programming at all and shouldn't be on SO in the first place. You should probably be asking such questions on stats.stackexchange.com or datascience.stackexchange.com instead.